# How to generate apk file in NetBeans?

Tags: java, android, mobile, netbeans, apk

How can I generate the apk file in NetBeans? Should I install some plug-ins? I already have the Android one. Or should I write something in command prompt? Is it a special one? How can i start it? Thank you!

Comment: but why are you using Netbeans? Use Eclipse or Android Studio stefana.

Comment: I use NetBeans because I am more familiar with it and also it is easier to use, from my point of view. Thanks.

Comment: ya you are right, but I think android development is more easy in eclipse and androidstudio, I have also like u before, NetBeans lover, but I was found lots of problems when developing. That's why suggested you.Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I wanted just to build APK I'd rather use command line directly. If you want to build and run your Android application using NetBeans then building APK is just part of that and it is possible with NBAndroid plugin. You can check brief documentation at http://nbandroid.org/wiki/index.php/NBAndroid#Deployment_to_a_device